# How to implement Google OAuth Login without googleplus plugin on cordova app?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I am trying to use Google OAuth for my application. As I have restrictions to not to use the Google Plus plugin or any other similar plugin, I tried the manual process like below on iOS (Cordova app, ionic).

I used *In-app browser* plugin, on a button click opens the google OAuth URL using `in-appbrowser` target as **_system** on the safari browser.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 scope=email%20profile&
 response_type=code&
 state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Foauth2.example.com%2Ftoken&
 redirect_uri=**reverse_client_id**%3A/oauth2redirect&
 client_id=***
```

The Google login screen comes, after entering the required details (username, password) it redirects to my app

The issue is when it redirects back it is not invoking the page (angular route) the app remains ideal. [redirect path: /oauth2]

How to handle redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I found couple of solutions

1. https://github.com/cmgustavo/Custom-URL-scheme#readme
2. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks

The first plugin has a method called `handleOpenURL`, using this the OAuth code can be captured.

```
(window as any).handleOpenURL = (url: string) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("handle open url called", url)
      }, 0);
    }
```

The URL that is captured above has a `code` that can be used to get the `access token`.

Answer (score 0):

To implement sign in with google in Angular you have to follow given steps:

1. Create a google app in google cloud console platform and generate a client id.
2. Create a new angular application.
3. Implement login with google using google OAuth 2.0 protocol.

You can read my article written on Codingvila [Angular 14 Login with Google using OAuth 2.0](https://www.codingvila.com/2022/07/angular-14-login-with-google-using-oauth.html) where I explained everything step by step with example.

You can also [download](https://www.codingvila.com/2022/07/angular-14-login-with-google-using-oauth.html) the sample example for your practice.